# Docker to deploy java web application with frequent configuration changes in wildfly server

Tags: docker, devops

I am new to DevOps. Recently I practiced the Docker examples. I have one usecase in my current project. Here it is

This is java project. It contains one war project that depends on jar project. Build tool is maven.

1. We are using Jboss Wildfly server.
2. DataBase is mysql 5.7.
3. We are using testng framework for the unit test cases.
4. sonarqube for code analysis. Selenium for testing.
5. So in any linux box the infrastructure we need is java8, wildfly server and mysql 5.7.
6. Consider we have 2 boxes. one is dev and another is test. Developer works on his local windows machine.
7. Sometimes we need some configurations required in jboss folder. Suppose we changed one xml in wildfly configuration folder in this release. How to communicate same to dev and test boxes as local machine. Another case is for dev box we need different configuration in xml and for test box it is different from dev box(SSL information in standalone.xml and user properties). How to handle this?

Comment: Do u mean by "Box" a Docker container? I understand that you want to be able to change configuration inside of the container without having to redploy it.

Comment: Sorry If my question is not perfect. I mean box is linux instance. We have seperate linux instances for development and testing. these linux instances are different not containers. Both dev and test linux instances have docker installed in them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run all required stack (wildfly and mysql) via docker-compose. Also you can extend official wildfly image to provide your custom configuration so you should build 2 different images, one with tag 'dev' and second with tag 'test'.